# how to use different dataframes on train/test split

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I have 6 different datasets in 6 different data frames

what I want is to use different datasets each time for the train/ test split. after that, I gonna fit this in an lstm network

so lets df1, df2, df3,df4, df5 in the train set and df6 in the test set

then df1, df2, df3, df4, df6 in the train test and df5 in the test set

and so on...

how can you make this happen? how to perform this train test split

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can just solve this simple way.

```
df_list = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6]
for i in range(6):
    train = pd.concat(df_list[0:i] + df_list[i+1:])
    test = df_list[i]
    # do your training.
```

Comment: i must perform the training inside the for?

Comment: @redplanet this is obvious from the answer. Each `for` iteration is equivalent to one CV fold - you have to fit & validate your model for each one.